# After upgrading from CF9 to CF10, website displays only blank screens

Tags: iis, iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I have successfully installed ColdFusion 10.  However my web site won't work without the previous Coldfusion 9 instance running.

It is like CF10 cannot see my IIS web site.  I do not get any errors when I try using CF10, it just doesn't render a screen (all blank).

Comment: Is the CF10 service/process running?

Comment: Have you Google'd any? www.carehart.org may have some helpful information for you on CF10 and IIS. Also, did you follow the instructions carefully? ColdFusion 10 runs on Tomcat and ColdFusion 9 ran on JRun.Finally, do you have any errors in the CF Exception log? I've observed "white pages" instead of a 404 or 500 "error page" and discovered the real cause in the logs.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a number of reasons for this, as quite a large number of people seem to be having issues with the upgrade to ColdFusion 10. Based on the information you've provided, it sounds like IIS is still connected to ColdFusion 9 rather than ColdFusion 10.

You can verify this by adding the following snippet to a ColdFusion page to output your ColdFusion version (when ColdFusion 9 is running):

```
<cfoutput>#SERVER.ColdFusion.ProductVersion#</cfoutput>
```

If it starts with 9, then IIS is connecting to the old ColdFusion version. If this is the case I would suggest rerunning the ColdFusion connector (for version 10). Instructions for using the configurator are available at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html but it should be a case of running this (the ColdFusion 10 configurator, not the ColdFusion 9 one), removing ColdFusion from all the IIS sites and then readding these entries in the configurator.

You should then find when loading a page ColdFusion 10 is used. If this doesn't work, you should ensure the ColdFusion 10 service is running review the log files as suggested by Aaron Greenlee.